# ArrayList.filter won't work

Tags: java, android, arrays, kotlin

So, I have this code for Android:

```
parkingList.removeIf { parking-> parking.city != pr.city }
parkingList.removeIf { parking-> parking.price.toDouble() <= pr.priceFrom }
parkingList.removeIf { parking-> parking.price.toDouble() >= pr.priceTo }
parkingList.removeIf { parking-> parking.daysBusy.contains(daysSet.split("|").toString()) }
```

This is code I have right now. I can't use anything else, because when I'm using filter to my arraylist parkingList, it won't work. And I don't know why. This is how I use it:

```
parkingList.filter { parking-> parking.city === pr.city }
parkingList.filter { parking-> parking.price.toDouble() >= pr.priceFrom }
parkingList.filter { parking-> parking.price.toDouble() <= pr.priceTo }
parkingList.filter { parking-> !parking.daysBusy.contains(daysSet.split("|").toString()) }
```

But for some reason it won't work.
P.S. I need only API19, so, this is the reason, why I must use only filter (Or no?)

**CODE:**

```
val filteredList = parkingList.filter { parking-> parking.city === pr.city
        parking.price.toDouble() >= pr.priceFrom
        parking.price.toDouble() <= pr.priceTo
        !parking.daysBusy.contains(daysSet.split("|").toString())
    } as ArrayList

filteredList.forEach { println(it) }
val adapter = CustomAdapter(filteredList)
```

Comment: @BackSlash wow. Well, uhm, after that, list is fully empty (But all conditions are right)...

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "doesn't work" isn't a working problem description!

Comment: @GhostCat ok...

Comment: @GhostCat well. I know, I have some problems with post description etc, but I don't understand well enough how to get it clearer. For ex., how you can see, I just can't use less code for my post, because not everybody can understand me without more code... Sometimes, even I can't understand parts of my code. I understand that this is bad, but I try to improve, even if it's badly seen.

Comment: @GhostCat and yes, thank you for this article, I'll try to use it for max

Comment: You are welcome. I appreciate your positive reaction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`removeIf` will envetually remove elements from the list on which you call it, it works *in-place*.

```
val originalList = arrayListOf(1,2,3,4)
originalList.removeIf { it % 2 == 0 }
// originalList.size is 2
```

`filter` on the other hand, will return a new list, so you need to use the returned value.

```
val originalList = listOf(1,2,3,4)
val filteredList = originalList.filter { it % 2 == 0 }
// originalList.size is 4
// filteredList.size is 2
```

Also, when you check for equality with `parking.city === pr.city`, that will return true only if `parking.city` and `pr.city` are the same object, it will return false even if the 2 objects have equal values, that is, if `equals(Any)` returns true

**update**

In your code you have 4 boolean expressions but only the last one is returned, you need to chain them with an operator, I added `&&` as an example but you need adjust that based on your business logic

```
filter { parking ->
    parking.city === pr.city &&
    parking.price.toDouble() >= pr.priceFrom &&
    parking.price.toDouble() <= pr.priceTo &&
    !parking.daysBusy.contains(daysSet.split("|").toString())
}
```

For instance, if you try to filter with

```
.filter {
    false
    true
}
```

All elements will be kept be cause the first `false` is going to be completely ignored, if you instead do

```
.filter {
    false &&
    true
}
```

The filtered list will have 0 elements because the filtering expression is now `false && true`

Comment: Okey. But I have many values. And when I use filter, it's just returning original list without filtering. I'll edit my question to add code in 3 minutes

Comment: Yes, it's the same objects. For ex. pr.city = "New York" and parking.city equal "New York" too.

Comment: I was just saying because it wasn't clear to me what the problem was, I updated my answer, you're basically ignoring the first 3 checks

Comment: I see. And, yeah, for some reason I forgot about &&. But even now it's just return empty list. May be it's because original list is arraylist and filtered it's just a list? (But when I'm trying to cast ArrayList nothing happens, oh well)

Comment: Well, it might be empty because you're filtering out all the elements, again I would suggest you to be careful with `===`, chances are you only need `==`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this code to filter out the element from array, by using this code:

    var day: List = arrayListOf("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday")


// to get the result as list


      var dayList: List = day.filter { s -> s == "Monday" }

// to get a a string

    var selectedDay: String = day.filter { s -> s == "`enter code here`Monday" }.single() 


     println("the value  is $dayList")
println("the value is $selectedDay")
```